# Hindi fornt issue in unity due to gpos and gsub?

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-3.0

I'm using hindi font devnagri but facing problem when copy pasting the hindi text..ie  when i type "small letter it show  halant with letter"i.e "adha  i want to show only small letter example i want to type film (फिल्म)in hindi ...but its showing filim i.e (फ िल् म) with halant and E ki matra instead . This is only happening in unity but with code removed the "e ki matra issue but still facing ल् halant issue.
i already tried kruti_dev ,mangal..but showing same issue every where .and keyboard for all these fonts are also different don't know why